# Adding method to asp.net identity login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Using asp.net identity, I've added a column to the `IdentityUser` table called `isActive`, which is a bit and will check if the user should be able to log in. To the Login Controller, I've added:

```
if (!await UserManager.IsUserActiveAsync(user.UserId))
{
    return View("AccountDisabled");
}
```

I've also added the following method to the `UserStore` class:

```
public Task<TUser> IsUserActiveAsync(Guid userId)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connection))
            {
                var param = new DynamicParameters();
                param.Add("@UserId", userId);
                var result = connection.Query<TUser>("IdentityCheckUserIsActive", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();

                return Task.FromResult(result);
            }
        }
```

But I'm getting the following error: `'IdentityUserManager' does not contain a definition for 'IsUserActiveAsync' and no extension method 'IsUserActiveAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IdentityUserManager' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I don't know what that means?

Comment: If you have `DbContext` in your code, then you can use `context.Database.Query<TUser>` which means you can take advantage of the `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` extension and `await` that rather than using `Task.FromResult`

Comment: I personally wouldn't add this method into the `UserStore` or the `UserManager` at all. You should create a new service for this. Unless you inherit from either of these classing adding the functionality in. But then you have to deal with all that casting.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an extension method like this:

```
public static class UserManagerExtensions 
{
    public static Task<TUser> IsUserActiveAsync(this UserManager mgr, Guid userId, string _connection)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connection))
        {
            var param = new DynamicParameters();
            param.Add("@UserId", userId);
            var result = connection.Query<TUser>("IdentityCheckUserIsActive", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();

            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would `_connection` come from??

Comment: @CallumLinington you could load it from a config file or pass it in as an argument

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to access a method of `UserManager` without an instance of it, so you can create an instance of it like so:

```
UserManager userManager = new UserManager(/*Params here if needed*/);
```

then you would just call:

```
if (!await userManager.IsUserActiveAsync(user.UserId))
{
    return View("AccountDisabled");
}
```

However if you want to be able to call the method from the class without instantiating an object you need to mark the method as static i.e.

```
public static Task<TUser> IsUserActiveAsync(Guid userId)
```

Comment: @CallumLinington Of course looking at what the method does, I was just stating another way of getting the functionality if that is what the OP wants

Comment: Yeah, I was just saying you should state that is a really bad thing to do, because others may come looking thinking that is a great idea, when it really isn't. That is all.

Comment: I' confused why the method I've added would require this, whereas there are many other very similar methods (i.e, `await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)`) in the same `Login` controller that do not?

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative method.

`UserManager` and `UserStore` are pre-built/defined classes to a do very specific functionality. I wouldn't try extending on them directly - I've been down that road and it isn't pretty.

What I would suggest is create a new service. One dedicated to getting you this information:

```
public interface IActiveUserService
{
    Task<bool> IsUserActiveAsync(Guid userId);
}

public class ActiveUserService : IActiveUserService
{
    private readonly DbContext context;

    // I generally have DI inject a factory and I use that to create my DbContext instance (this is the prefered method)
    // for simplicity I have just pass DbContext
    // if you stick with this, 
    // you should make sure this service is constructed per request
    public ActiveUserService(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsUserActiveAsync(Guid userId) 
    {
         var connection = this.dbContext.Database.Connection   ;

         // I assume from this you are using Dapper??
         var param = new DynamicParameters();
         param.Add("@UserId", userId);
         var result = await connection
                               .Query<TUser>(
                                   "IdentityCheckUserIsActive", 
                                   param, 
                                   commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                               .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

         return result.IsActive;
    }
}
```

In your consumer class:

```
if (!await this.activeUserService.IsUserActiveAsync(user.UserId))
{
    return View("AccountDisabled");
}
```